# CKEDITOR force VSPACE and HSPACE on images

Tags: outlook, ckeditor

I'm working on an email editor using the last ckeditor version.

To provide compatibility with outlook, I need to force HSPACE and VSPACE on images.

I found some workarounds that have been working on previous ckeditor version.

Now CKEDITOR output is:

```
<p><img alt="" src="/userfiles/images/river.jpg" style="float:left; height:900px; margin:10px; width:1600px" /></p>
```

I need something like:

```
<p><img alt="" src="/userfiles/images/river.jpg" align="left" vspace="10" hspace="10" /></p>
```

Any idea how to achieve that on the last ckeditor version?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you post the text with hspace and vspace as ckeditor formats it and the format that Outlook expects it in? And / or give us the previous workaround and what has changed with the new version?

Comment: @mseifert thanks for your answer. The question is edited. Here is the old workaround http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Image-VSPACE-and-HSPACE

Comment: Without making the effort to modify ckeditor (which that old post demonstrates is possible), a simpler solution would be to do a data.replace() when saving the output from the editor and replace the style with what you want.

Comment: Thanks again @mseifert. Can you post an example? I not sure the correct place to make the replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My method would be simpler than modifying ckeditor. I would attempt to do something like the following. Disclaimer, the regex here probably doesn't work as written. Regex is not my strength and it takes a lot of research and time for me to get it right. And depending on the various possibilities for your output, you might have to loop through multiple images if each has different needs. But as an idea.... I am replacing the whole style statement with the vspace and hspace settings. Note, `editor` is the name of your instance of the editor

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData();
        data = data.replace(/<style=(.*)>/g, 'align="left" vspace="10" hspace="10"');
        CKEDITOR.instances.editor.setData(data);
    };
```

Comment: Thank you. That did not solved my problem, but certainly give me some ideas that I could try.